# Qlik CURL With Authentication

Tags: php, curl, get, request

I'm trying to get authenticated with Qlik using php and not having much luck.
But I found this code snippet online and just wanting to know how I could achieve this same type of request using CURL and PHP.

```
$objHTTP = ObjCreate("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
$objHTTP.open ("GET", "http://localhost/qrs/app/?Xrfkey=ABDHEFUELPYRVGLK", False,"my usernamer","my password")
$objHTTP.setRequestHeader("X-Qlik-Xrfkey","ABDHEFUELPYRVGLK")
$objHTTP.send()
$data = $objHTTP.responseText
```

This must be a GET request.

Comment: A cURL request will always use GET (it's the default) unless you're specifically setting some other method. Have you actually tried anything? SO isn't a code translation service. You should try something and come back when you run into some _specific_ issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem it use `GET` request with `basic authentication`.
Please try this

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/qrs/app/?Xrfkey=ABDHEFUELPYRVGLK');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Qlik-Xrfkey: ABDHEFUELPYRVGLK"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Really? Ok the reason I'm having these issues is that I'm trying to authenticate from a php script and it wont let me retrieve a token. It throws this error: "Error 403 - Forbidden. The initial authentication request must be a &quot;GET&quot; request in order to be redirected to the authentication module.". do you have any good suggestions for qlik auth with a ticket? Thank you

Comment: this is the link to my question in the Qlik community: https://community.qlik.com/thread/266269?sr=inbox&ru=218859. Thank you for your help

Comment: If you can help I've opened up a new question regarding this. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899740/qlik-auth-with-php